# How to find top 6 columns from table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Below are the columns I have in the table called TEMP2,

```
[ID],[Week1], [Week2],[Week3],[Week4],[Week5], 
[Week6],[Week7],[Week8],[Week9], [Week10],
[Week11],[Week12],[Week13], [Week14],[Week15],
[Week16],[Week17], [Week18],[Week19],[Week20],
[Week21], [Week22],[Week23],[Week24],[Week25], [Week26]
```

I want to find the top 6 records from each row and display.

Below is the query I tried using for the same and is not fetching the expected result. What I'm doing wrong here?

```
SELECT 
    id, [1], [2], [3],[4], [5], [6]
    FROM 
    (SELECT 
        id, Val, rn
        FROM 
        (SELECT id, Val, Col,
            ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Val) 
            AS rn
                FROM 
                TEMP2
    UNPIVOT 
    (Val FOR Col IN ([Week1],
    [Week2],[Week3],[Week4],[Week5],[Week6],[Week7],[Week8],[Week9],
    [Week10],[Week11],[Week12],[Week13],[Week14],[Week15],[Week16],[Week17],
    [Week18],[Week19],[Week20],[Week21],[Week22],[Week23],[Week24],[Week25],
    [Week26]))AS unpvt) AS t
        WHERE 
        t.rn <= 6) AS src
            PIVOT 
            (MAX(Val) FOR rn IN ([1], [2], [3],[4], [5], [6])) AS pvt
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Could you add an example output you expected and the result you get with your query above?

Comment: `PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Val DESC`, surely, if you want to assign the numbers 1-6 to the *highest* values of `Val` rather than the lowest.

Comment: The person who down voted can explain me the reason for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) in the comments above, it seems you just need to `ORDER BY Val DESC` in your `PARTITION BY` statement, to return the largest values first.

This worked for me on some test data I set up:

```
SELECT 
    id, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]
    FROM 
    (SELECT 
        id, Val, rn
        FROM 
        (SELECT id, Val, Col,
            ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Val DESC) 
            AS rn
                FROM 
                TEMP2
    UNPIVOT 
    (Val FOR Col IN ([Week1],
    [Week2],[Week3],[Week4],[Week5],[Week6],[Week7],[Week8],[Week9],
    [Week10],[Week11],[Week12],[Week13],[Week14],[Week15],[Week16],[Week17],
    [Week18],[Week19],[Week20],[Week21],[Week22],[Week23],[Week24],[Week25],
    [Week26]))AS unpvt) AS t
        WHERE 
        t.rn <= 6) AS src
            PIVOT 
            (MAX(Val) FOR rn IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])) AS pvt
```

Comment: No problem, credit should go to [Damien_The_Unbeliever](http://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) though really.